# Problems installing Sencha command line tools

Tags: javascript, linux, sencha-touch-2, linux-mint

I have tried installing Sencha command line tools several times but I am still stuck. Here is the output from my command-line.

```
$ projects/sencha-touch-2.2.0 → sencha

node.js:201
throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
^
Error: Cannot find module '/media/me/DATA/projects/sencha-touch-2.2.0/command/sencha.js'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:332:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
    at Array.0 (module.js:479:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)


$ cat ~/.zshrc
...
# sencha touch sdk
PATH=$PATH:/opt/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3/:/opt/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3/bin
SENCHA_SDK_TOOLS_2_0_0_BETA3=/opt/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3
# Added by install script for node.js and npm in 30s
export PATH=$HOME/local/bin:$PATH
export NODE_PATH=$HOME/local/lib/node_modules

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

$ projects/sencha-touch-2.2.0 → node --version
v0.10.6
$ projects/sencha-touch-2.2.0 → ruby --version
ruby 2.0.0p195 (2013-05-14 revision 40734) [x86_64-linux]
```

I have found on different forums that I need version 3+ of the SDK tools but the only download I am able to get for Linux is labelled SenchaCmd-3.1.2.342-linux-x64.run and I hope that it is the correct installation file.

Can you please help me get this working on my OS? [Linux Mint 14 (Ubuntu 12.x)]

Comment: With ST2.2 you need to use Sencha CMD and NOT Sencha SDK Tools. You can remove it and install Sencha CMD instead (unless you still work with an older version of the SDK with certain apps)

Comment: Thanks. I don't think I have installed the SDK. What I've done so far is to unzip the Sencha Touch 2.2 files, install the Sencha CMD, go into the Sencha Touch 2.2 directory, Created an empty file callend .senchasdk (so that the command line tool will recognise that dir as an SDK directory) and run 'sencha'

Comment: When I say SDK I mean the framework (Sencha Touch 2.2)

Comment: But with just the command line tools if I run `sencha` outside of the SDK I get a WARNING message that this directory is not an SDK directory :-( Ok ok. I know what you mean because I have been able to install this on a Mac and Windows at work but I use Linux at home. How about we paraphrase the question - How do I install/get to work Sencha command line tools version 3+ on Linux? Thanks for your patience

Comment: I'm not on Linux but it should be as simple as on Mac or Windows. You download it and install it. What does the console return when you execute 'which sencha' ?

Comment: $~ → which sencha
/opt/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3//sencha

Comment: Then you need to uninstall SDK Tools and install Sencha Command (Cmd) instead (if not already done)

Comment: Thanks. I have Sencha Command installed but I will try uninstalling it and trying again.